# Can I hook up a smart thermostat to a "high efficiency gas forced air heater"? Are there any caveats?

Tags: thermostat, heating

I got some [help from folks here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214637/is-there-a-reason-i-shouldnt-use-an-oil-radiator-to-heat-a-1400-sq-ft-130-sq-m) identifying this as a gas unit heater.

I'm wondering if it's safe to replace the thermostat with a smart thermostat, and if there are any caveats,  E.G.  minimum on and cool down settings. (*Should I be wary of regular home heating advice given this kind of heater, or am I over worrying?*)

The main reason I want to get a new thermostat is that [this thing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002IXE2G0) currently reaches target temperature, turns off, then kicks back on when it falls 1 F (*or not even, it seems*), which is way too often for my poorly insulated apartment. I'd prefer something like 5 F.

[image]

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the nameplate and/or wiring diagram on the unit please?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a ladder to get close enough. But I had someone come by today and appears to work fine. Thanks for your interest in helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be perfectly fine. The internal control and safeties of the heater will prevent most bad™ things from happening.

A smart thermostat will come preprogrammed with reasonable defaults for hysteresis and min turn on.

One additional thing you should consider adding is a CO detector, which will alert in case the unit starts emitting the toxic odorless and colorless gas into your living space.